# Retain Vector Names as Dataframe Column Names

Tags: r

In my code, I am filling the columns of a dataframe with vectors, as so:

```
df1[columnNum] <- barWidth
```

This works fine, except for one thing: I want the name of the vector variable (`barWidth` above) to be retained as the column header, one column at a time. Furthermore, I do not wish to use `cbind`. This slows the execution of my code down considerably. Consequently, I am using a pre-allocated dataframe.

Can this be done in the vector-to-column assignment? If not, then how do I change it after the fact? I can't find the right syntax to do this with `colNames()`.

TIA

Comment: `cbind()` retains names, so I'd rethink my approach there.

Comment: This can probably be done, but I agree with Joris that reconsidering your code structure is smarter. Maybe you could explain why you really need this structure?

Comment: @JorisMeys I'd prefer not to use `cbind` since it slows my code down considerably. Using a pre-allocated dataframe and then filling in the data executes much quicker. Sorry, I should have explianed my rationale for using the above structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the list of *names* of vectors you want to apply you could do:

```
namevec <- c(...,"barWidth"...,)
columnNums <- c(...,10,...)

df1[columnNums[i]] <- get(namevec[i])
names(df1)[columnNums[i]] <- namevec[i]
```

or even

```
columnNums <- c(barWidth=4,...)
for (i in seq_along(columnNums)) {
   df1[columnNums[i]] <- get(names(columnNums)[i])
}
names(df1)[columnNums] <- names(columnNums)
```

but the deeper question would be where this set of vectors is coming from in the first place: could you have them in a list all along?

Answer (score 2):

It's being done by the `[<-.data.frame` function. It could conceivably be replaced by one that looked at the name of the argument but it's such a fundamental function I would be hesitant. Furthermore there appears to be an aversion to that practice signaled by this code at the top of the function definition:

```
> `[<-.data.frame`
function (x, i, j, value) 
{
    if (!all(names(sys.call()) %in% c("", "value"))) 
        warning("named arguments are discouraged")
    nA <- nargs()
    if (nA == 4L) {
 <snipped rest of rather long definition>
```

I don't know why that is there, but it is. Maybe you should either be thinking about using `names<-` after the column assignment, or using this method:

```
> dfrm["barWidth"] <- barWidth

> dfrm
  a V2 barWidth
1 a  1        1
2 b  2        2
3 c  3        3
4 d  4        4
```

This can be generalized to a list of new columns:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(a=letters[1:4])
barWidth <- 1:4
newcols <- list(barWidth=barWidth, bw2 =barWidth)
dfrm[names(newcol)] <- newcol
dfrm
#
  a barWidth bw2
1 a        1   1
2 b        2   2
3 c        3   3
4 d        4   4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use `cbind()`:

```
 df1 <- cbind( df1, barWidth )
```

which retains the name. It will, however, end up as the last column in `df1`